# Password of rabbitmq system user

Tags: rabbitmq

It's written in the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html) that RabbitMQ server

> is set up to run as system user  rabbitmq

What is the default password of the user?

Answer (score 70):

Defaults :

```
Username: guest
Password: guest
```

Comment: this  user is used for rabbitmq usage (management ui and applications). i'm asking about system user - rabbitmq, rabbitmq-server was installed with

Comment: You don't need to know password. sudo su  - rabbitmq. You can change password by passwd  command if you want

Comment: i do need, that's my question

Comment: `# su - rabbitmq` will change to user. You just need to have root access, it will not ask password.
or set up new password by:

`# passwd rabbitmq`

it will not ask for password but you must run those command from `root` user

Answer (score 5):

There is no default password for a Linux user.  The password can be set during account creation; if it isn't set, then it won't exist, and password auth is disabled for that user (/etc/shadow will show the password as '!!').  Without knowing the password (or it existing), it can only be changed/set by root.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no default password for the system user `rabbitmq`, so switching with `su` will always ask for password unless one makes some changes in the sudoers file or are logged in as root.

One instead can use sudo to run commands as the `rabbitmq` user. For example, `sudo -u rabbitmq <command>`.